# How to grab all cookies in Flash

Tags: flash, cookies

For a site I'm developing with a user login that uses cookies to store the session ID, a separate section of it uses Flash to provide content and such. Is there some way it can access the cookies that were set the by login? The name of the cookie will not the be same every time, as it is randomly generated, as well as its value. I then need to send the name and value of the cookie back to a page on the server to do additional stuff. Anyone know how to do this? Note that I didn't write the Flash interface, an the person who did doesn't know how to do this. Please help me, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use the 'scriptData' array to pass anything you wish through POST